# Moving data from one model to another in django admin changelist

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two model in my Django Admin: UpcomingEvents and ArchivedEvents. Both of them have the same attributes which are like this :

```
class UpcomingEvents(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Organizer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Start_Time = models.DateTimeField(help_text='in EST')
    End_Time = models.DateTimeField(help_text='in EST')
    Status_choices = ((1,'Upcoming'),(2,'Completed'),(3,'Cancelled'))
    Status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=Status_choices, default=1, max_length=50)
```

What I want to achieve is that when some user changes the status of a change within the UpcomingEvents from Upcoming to Completed or Cancelled,it should disappear from the changelist of UpcomingEvents and appear in the change list of ArchivedEvents and vice versa.How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't you simplify it, but creating one model "Event" with status attribute? Moreover you can then create a custom manager, so you can get events like : `Event.objects.upcoming() or Event.objects.archived()`, if you dont want to use `.filter(status="upcoming")`

Comment: Not really..I do not want to filter out the events by status..I want to have two change lists with the ability to move data from one to another